# Apply expression on string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm new to batch and I know that you can use

```
%~dp0
```

to get the directory from a path, but then how do I use it on a path and put it into a variable.

Say I have this Location:

```
C:\someFolderName\anotherFolderName\FinalFolderName\file.txt
```

I want to know what the path is(excluding the drive and the file) and store it into a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tilde notation works for `for` loop variables and `call` function arguments.  Check out this sample .bat script for an example of each method:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "fqname=C:\someFolderName\anotherFolderName\FinalFolderName\file.txt"

rem // set var1 to the path-to-file
for %%I in ("%fqname%") do set "var1=%%~dpI"

rem // set var2 to the path-to-file
call :get_path var2 "%fqname%"

echo var1: %var1%
echo var2: %var2%

rem // end main runtime
goto :EOF

rem // get_path function
:get_path <var_to_set> <filename>
set "%~1=%~dp2"
goto :EOF
```

In a cmd window, enter `help for` and see the last couple of pages for full details on tilde notation.